# Downgrade Galaxy Grand Prime SM-G530H to Kitkat

Tags: device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-grand

I upgraded my SM-G530H to 5.0.2 via the phone Software Updater a long time ago. Now I want to downgrade it and flash the stock 4.4.4 ROM via Odin but it fails with this log

```
<ID:0/010> Added!!
<ID:0/010> Odin v.3 engine (ID:10)..
<ID:0/010> File analysis..
<ID:0/010> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/010> Initialzation..
<ID:0/010> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/010> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/010> aboot.mbn
<ID:0/010> NAND Write Start!!
<ID:0/010> FAIL! (Auth)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

After some search people say the ROM must have the same baseband version to flash. But I can't find any Kitkat ROM on [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-G530H/XXV/) that match my baseband (it's looks like Kitkat baseband is different from Lollipop's one)

So anyone can share a method to downgrade to stock Kitkat on SM-G530H?

I had previously installed a custom recovery (TWRP 3.1.0) and my baseband version is `G530HXCS1BQA1`

Comment: Most devices would not allow a downgrade, at least not a downgrade operation that involves the bootloader.

Comment: I know what the bootloader is but can you explain the "involves the bootloader" part? I'm still new in the android customizer world.

Comment: If the downgrade process downgrades the bootloader itself, usually it will not be allowed.